# How to show currency sign after the value on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, double, currency, currency-formatting

I'm trying to show price `<double>` value on an `.aspx` page with this code:

```
<%# string.Format("{0:C2}", Eval("price")) %>
```

My current result:

```
$12.50
```

Expected result:

```
12.50$
```

Comment: Is there a language or culture that uses this? You might be able to use that.

Comment: Your code should be correct, I guess it has some thing with your culture setting.

Comment: Web site running with 4 language and all the currency signs appears before value. @wazz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use decimal i think and put the dollar sign outside the formatting.

```
<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("price")) %>$

<%# string.Format("{0:D}", Eval("price")) %>$ // ?
```

Also check:

```
<%# string.Format("{0:0.00}", Eval("price")) %>$
```

Comment: Of course this will work only when the currency required is $.

Comment: thanks, i have tried this working example and i will add money signs manually like this method. {0:C2} format shows signs automatically and changing with language.

Comment: @Mert Take a look at the pair [CurrencyNegativePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern?view=netframework-4.8) and [CurrencyPositivePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Steve thank you steve i am looking at that useful resources.